# Append file path to csv file which contains the file name

Tags: powershell, csv, append, filepath

I would like to add the full path of files to a CSV that contains the file names.

So in the csv I have currently:

file1.txt
file2.txt

Export csv should look like:

file1.txt; c:/temp/file1.txt
file1.txt; c:/temp/file1.txt

I tried the following:

```
$csv = Import-Csv <location csv>


    $allItems = Get-ChildItem -Recurse <location folders/files>
    $fullname = @()

    foreach ($item in $csv)
    {
      $fullname += $a | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $file} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname
    }
```

Comment: Are file1.txt and file2.txt separated by a space or are they on separate lines? If they are separated by a space only, are there ever any file names with spaces?

Comment: separated by ; and yes there are file names which contain spaces

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV input file looks like this:

```
"FileName"
"file1.txt"
"file2 with spaces.txt"
"some other file.blah"
```

then you can use `$files = (Import-Csv <location csv>).FileName` to get a string array of the filenames you are after.

If (judging by your comment) the inputfile is a single string with filenames separated by semi-colons `;` this is the way to go:

```
$files = (Get-Content <location csv> -Raw) -split ';'
```

Using that array of filenames you can do the following:

```
$result = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path $searchPath -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    if ($files -contains $_.Name) {
        if ($result.ContainsKey($_.Name)) {
            $result[$_.Name] += (';{0}' -f $_.FullName)
        }
        else {
            $result.Add($_.Name, $_.FullName)
        }
    }
}
# convert the hashtable to an array of PSCustomObjects and export to csv
$result.Keys | 
    ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{ FileName = $_ ; FullName = $result.$_ }} | 
    Export-Csv -Path $output -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Assume your searchpath includes this:

```
D:\TEST
|   file1.txt
|   file2 with spaces.txt
|   some other file you are not interested in.txt
|
\---subfolder
        file2 with spaces.txt
```

Then the outputted CSV file from the code above will be:

> ```
> "FileName","FullName"
> "file2 with spaces.txt","D:\Test\file2 with spaces.txt;D:\Test\subfolder\file2 with spaces.txt"
> "file1.txt","D:\Test\file1.txt"
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look.